# Do the /odom topic and odom->base_link tf provide duplicate information?

Tags: ros, navigation, odometry, base-link, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm making a differential-drive rover with wheel encoders and planar LIDAR, but at the moment no other sensors.
I understand why it's useful to have [separate `map` and `odom` frames](http://answers.ros.org/question/237295/confused-about-coordinate-frames-can-someone-please-explain/)--if my wheel odometry was perfect, the transform between the two would be zero, but it's not, so mapping (gmapping at the moment) is needed to find ithe correcting transform. I've implemented a publisher of both `nav_msgs.msg.Odometry` as topic `/odom` and `tf.TransformBroadcaster` as a transform between `odom` and `base_link`, according to [this tutorial](http://library.isr.ist.utl.pt/docs/roswiki/navigation(2f)Tutorials(2f)RobotSetup(2f)Odom.html).

However, it doesn't seem that the `odom -> base_link` transformation provides any information that isn't already present in my `/odom` topic. Are there other cases in which these would be different, and I'm just not very imaginative? Is the separate existence of the tf just for the (perhaps significant) convenience of having a homogeneous way to transform between `odom` and `map` frames? In that case, maybe it would be possible not to publish the `/odom` topic, since the only extra thing it has is velocities, which I just approximate as the difference from the last message over time increment.

FWIW, my code is [here](https://github.com/tsbertalan/gunnar), and in particular **[this script](https://github.com/tsbertalan/gunnar/blob/master/scripts/hardwareDriver) contains the publisher of both the `/odom` topic and the broadcaster of the `odom -> base_link` transformation**. I might later solicit comments on the larger project, but at the moment it's a bit disorganized because of a relatively recent jettisoning of Arduino as a bridge to hardware.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/248783/do-the-/odom-topic-and-odom-%3Ebase_link-tf-provide-duplicate-information?/) by [tsbertalan](https://answers.ros.org/users/28618/tsbertalan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2016-11-24

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup/Odom says that tf doesn't provide velocity so the navigation stack also wants the `Odometry` message.  tf does provide a lookupTwist function but it either is averaging the velocity over a time period or computing velocity from the last two position updates- the averaging could have a lot of latency or smooth over short duration velocities of interest, and only using the last updates could be noisy.  So neither method can recover the instantaneous velocity of the odom message.  http://answers.ros.org/question/12894/calculating-velocity-from-tf/

It doesn't mention it but the Odom message also has position and velocity uncertainty information in the pose and twist covariance matrices- it is said to be optional but but a pose filtering scheme would make use of that when fusing odometry with imu or other sensor data.
(There is an unmaintained tf version that propagates uncertainty http://wiki.ros.org/uncertain_tf , it would be great if this was revived in the future, and then later support multiple tf parents as well...)

If you have no current or potential subscribers to /odom in your project (doesn't gmapping want it or is it using only sensors?) then it could be eliminated, or made optional (Maybe someone else will want to hook your robot up to the nav stack- and does it really cost you much resources to keep publishing it?).

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2016-11-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tsbertalan](https://answers.ros.org/users/28618/tsbertalan/) on 2016-11-25**:
I see. In that case, maybe I should change the way I report vx, vy, vtheta. At the moment, they're indistinguishable from what you might get from tf, but I it might be useful to get the full noisy signal from within my encoder interrupt functions.

**Comment by [Karthikey97](https://answers.ros.org/users/32828/karthikey97/) on 2017-12-01**:
So in that case, is the being sent over the tf broadcaster redundant. I'm saying this as the the nav_msgs/odometry seems to have all the required information (velocity and the pose of the robot with covariance in the odom frame).